# "A similar trend can be observed with Banking sector" vs "in the Finance sector"

Tags: prepositions, articles

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

When I write "A similar trend can be observed with **Banking** sector" everything seems to be alright, but when I change it to "A similar trend can be observed with **Finance** sector", the app suggests correcting it to "observed **in the** Finance sector".

Why is it so? Is there something that grammatically separates banking from finance? Which option would sound natural here?

Comment: You should have written 'the banking sector' too, but the grammar app didn't pick that up. There is no such thing as a good, reliable grammar app. Also, it didn't pick up your wrong capitalisation of 'Banking' and 'Finance'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a flaw in an unidentified machine grammar checker whose recurrence is impossible to predict. As such, any answer is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Both "banking" and "finance" are particular sectors, and thus need a definite article "the"  in this sort of use. The phrase  "A similar trend can be observed with Banking sector" will generally be understood, but will mark the writer as not fluent in English.

As [this page from the Purdue writing lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html) says:

> English has two articles: the and a/an. The is used to refer to specific or particular nouns; a/an is used to modify non-specific or non-particular nouns. We call the the definite article and a/an the indefinite article.
>
> **The** is used to refer to a specific or particular member of a group. For example, "I just saw **the** most popular movie of the year." There are many movies, but only one particular movie is the most popular. Therefore, we use **the**.

See also [this tip sheet](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html) Many additional discussions of articles in English grammar can be found on the web.

I must agree with Michael Harvey who wrote in a comment "There is no such thing as a good, reliable grammar app." At best, take an app or program's comments as suggestions. Never assume that the app finds all errors or that what it approves must be correct.